# css using data/image not working in browsers

Tags: html, css

I have this css code

```
.imagetrackuser {max-width: 24px;max-height: 18px;background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)}
```

and when i try to call this cod in my html page with a class, it shows nothing, i tested in chrome

```
<button type="button"> <i class="imagetrackuser"></i> </button>
```

and its not working for any of the browser, what i am missing here

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: can you clarify please, did not understood what you mean by it does not have height / width, so should i use div or span or any other tag which has width/height but stays on same location

Comment: i copied from one of the premium iconfinder websites, not sure its wrong ontheir part, but when i hover it, it shows me the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few things you needed to tweak in your class to show the icon;

```
.imagetrackuser {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 18px;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2..... etc
```

You need to make the element an `inline-block` & actually set the `width` & `height`.

The `url` on the `background-image` is missing `""` & then as you're setting it as a background image, it needs to have a `background-size` & you're best also having an `background-repeat` set as `no-repeat`.

I have a working example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozwt9uc6/7/).

Comment: you nailed, Thanks Very much for guiding and elaborating as to what i was missing here, even the website which offers free icons as i am premium member does not give right CSS